# Tengo python 3.7 pero en sublime text la version que carga es la 2.7 en linux mint

Tags: python, terminal, sublimetext3, sublimetext, linux-mint

Uso linux mint1.8 y al usar el editor sublime text y cargar python para utilizarlo me sale la version 2.7 de python, y yo ya actualicé python en mi pc a el 3.7 pero en el editor sigue igual, lo desinstalé y lo instale de nuevo y sigue igual.

¿Alguien conoce por qué pasa esto?

*PSDT:* No soy muy conocedor de linux y tampoco de la programación - ando aprendiendo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que necesitas hacer la ejecución con la sintaxis:

```
$ python3 mi_programa.py
```

Se realiza la ejecución de Python 2.X porque hasta donde sé, el Sistema trae integrada esa versión. Ignoro si Sublime Text trae una terminal ya que hace mucho que no utilizo ese IDE, pero, si trae la terminal, mira si puedes hacer la ejecución desde ahí con esa sintaxis.

Comment: hola gracias por tu respuesto, pero esto no me funciono:(, lo hice en las dos terminales y nada:/

Comment: Date una vuelta por esta página para "preparar" sublime text para la programación en Python. Personalmente yo utilizo Visual Studio Code y hasta ahora no eh tenido ningún problema con algún lenguaje/ejecución       https://hackpuntes.com/preparando-sublime-text-3-programar-python/